# Django Admin: How do I know when the user is editing an existing object or saving a new object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I would like to learn how to work with the Django Admin. How do I know when the user is editing an existing object or saving a new object?

For example, if I want to make a function to do something different when the user saves a new object or saves an edited object, how do I know which is which?

Thanks guys :)

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def save(self):
        if self.id != None:
            print "Edited object"
        else:
            print "New object"
        super(MyModel, self).save()
```

Comment: The id attribute of the model would be None if you are saving it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could do one  of the following:

1. Listening for Django signals. In your case the [pre_save signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) could be useful.
2. Overwriting [ModelAdmin.save_model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)
3. Overwriting your models save method like described by Adam